# Email Field not available in "Available Recipients"

Tags: email, email-alert

I'm trying to create email alert. I started from creating Email field in my object, however I cannot see it in "Available Recipients". Do you have any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the technician email field is existing one or newly created? If it is new then refresh the page and check.

Comment: Check whether the email field you created has datatype as email not text.